# Partial expectation with indicator function

Tags: probability, probability-theory, expectation

I'm having trouble with proving the following problem, I think partial expectation should be used to solve this but can't figure it out.

Show that:

$E[X \cdot I(X\leq x)] = e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^{2}} \Phi(\frac{ln(x)-\mu-\sigma^{2}}{\sigma})$

where $I$ is the indicator function and $X$ is log-normal distributed with parameter $\mu$ and $\sigma$, i.e. $X \sim LN(\mu, \sigma^{2})$.

Appreciate if I can get some help with this and hopefully this is sufficient information but comment if you guys need more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $Y=log X\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $x>0$,
$$E[X\cdot I(X\leq x)]=E[e^Y\cdot I(e^Y\leq x)]=E[e^Y\cdot I(Y\leq \log x)]=
\int_{-\infty}^{\log x} e^y \dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}\ dy=\int_{-\infty}^{\log x} \dfrac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{(y-\mu)^2-2y\sigma^2}{2\sigma^2}}\ dy$$

Next completing the square in $(y-\mu)^2-2y\sigma^2=(y-(\mu+\sigma^2))^2-2\mu\sigma^2-\sigma^4$ and put it back into the exponent in the above integral. The answer will follow.

Comment: So the indicator inside the expectation tell us the bounds in which we integrate along? Is it wrong to think of the indicator inside the expectation as a random variable multiplying the $e^{Y}$

Comment: It is a random variable multiplying by $e^Y$, but this r.v. is a function of $Y$, and it is equal to either $0$ or $1$: 
$$E[e^Y\cdot I(Y\leq \log x)]=E[g(Y)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(y)f_Y(y)\,dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^y\cdot I(y\leq \log x) f_Y(y)\,dy = \int_{-\infty}^{\log x} e^y f_Y(y)\,dy$$

Comment: @WillHunting After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you can "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/).